# Extracting data from array (interpolation)

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I need some advice regarding a problem I encountered in MATLAB:

I have 4 variables, I'm not sure what is the best methodology to go about doing this. I initially thought about just computing the GreatCircle distance from each grid point to the specified location and return the corresponding row/column index that has the minimum distance. But doing it this way, I'm not sure how I can compute the interpolation.

I tried reshaping the data into a vector data of 4 columns and running meshgrid to possibly utilize interp2. But I ended up with this error:

> Requested 109620x109620 (44.8GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference

What could be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your matrices? May `Latitude` and  `Longitude` already be a meshgrid?

Answer (score 0):

You are working on large arrays. If `interp2` cannot handle it, work on a subarray instead:

```
% Create data
format shortG
[Latitude,Longitude] = meshgrid(1:12,1:12);
Altitude = floor(1000+sortrows(rand(12,12))*1000);
Temperature = 10+20*rand(12,12);

Lat = 2.1;
Lon = 11.8;

% Find closest match point
[~,i_Lat] = min(abs(Latitude(1,:)-Lat));
[~,i_Lon] = min(abs(Longitude(:,1)-Lon));

% Select subarrays around this point. 
% Minimum size of these matrices depend on the type of interpolation you perform
ia1 = max(1,i_Lat-5);
ia2 = min(size(Latitude,1),i_Lat+5);
io1 = max(1,i_Lon-5);
io2 = min(size(Latitude,2),i_Lon+5);

subLatitude = Latitude(io1:io2,ia1:ia2);
subLongitude = Longitude(io1:io2,ia1:ia2);
subAltitude = Altitude(io1:io2,ia1:ia2);
subTemperature = Temperature(io1:io2,ia1:ia2);

% Interpolate on these small arrays, and evaluate at target (Lat, Lon) point
A_out = interp2(subLatitude, subLongitude, subAltitude, Lat, Lon)
T_out = interp2(subLatitude, subLongitude, subTemperature, Lat, Lon)
```

Comment: Thank you Laure for your advice, may I know why is there -5/+5 in ia and io computations?

Comment: @Corse. You want to interpolate only into a subset of the array around your target point. The +-5 is arbitrary (with linear interpolation +-2 will work as well).

Comment: I see. What value should this be if a spline interpolation for interp2 should be used? I'm guessing -5/+5 will do, right? This basically gives slightly more data points to use in the interpolation?

Comment: I just answered you above. Use the code I provided.